# Semi-convergence matrix error bound

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, dynamical-systems

I have matrix A_nxn with the following properties:

1. primitive (the corresponding graph is strongly connected and has at least 2 coprime length cycles).
2. non-negative
3. largest eigenvalue equal to 1, and it's simple, and strictly greater than others in absolute value.
4. **Not** **symmetric**, and the corresponding graph is **not** **regular**

I have the following equation:
X(t+1) = A*X(t) (X is vector).
Also we can write:
X(t) = A^(t)*X(0)
This equation semi-convergence when t->infinity (convergence to the eigenvector **V1** corresponding to the eigenvalue 1).

My question is:
There is any analytic upper bound of the error: E = norm(A^(t)*X(0) - V1) ?
Especially with graph structure interpretation.